# How to block URLs different than main domain with Apache?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I want to block all request (or return 404 apaches error page) in my Wordpress different than the main url.

Example:

- https://myurl.com  this must work
- https://myurl.com/fksdofiewoq  this musnt work
- https://myurl.com/wp-admin  must work
- myurl.com/mainpost   must work clicking in the post in the main page.

Is there any posibility?

Comment: Have a look at running Fail2Ban on your server as an intrusion detection system. Also you should be able to create a WP 404 page that redirects to https://myurl.com (after a short delay) https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

Comment: Yes, i know this app but for this question i wanted to do it by apache. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-login.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/hello-world/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(pdf|jpeg|css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$
RewriteRule . / [R=404,L]
```

This can filter that uris and block the rest of urls